# jquery datepicker onclick help

Tags: jquery, function, datepicker, onclick

I'm developing with php and trying to work jquery's datepicker into my app. I'm trying to display a datepicker that's tied to a particular input field. I have the following code. The problem is that the first time i click on the input, nothing happens. Only when I unfocus and then reclick on it will it display the picker. How do i get it to display the datepicker on the first click?

```
<script>
function open_picker(X)
    {
        $( X ).datepicker({
            autoSize: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true });       
    };
</script>
<?php $datepickerid = "datepicker" ?>
<input id='<?php echo $datepickerid; ?>' onClick='open_picker("<?php echo "#".$datepickerid; ?>");' type='text' value='05/21/2011' size='10'>
```

I need to pass the input ID's through a function because i will be using a php loop to produce the datepicker inputs with different ID's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) your function open_picker() is not opening a date picker. What that code does is binding a date picker to the input passed as parameter X. That's why on first click nothing happens: because the date picker is *created* on first click.
What you need to do to create multiple datepickers by php is something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <?php
   $datepickers_ids = array("#all", "#the", "#datepickers", ".selectors");
   for($i = 0; $i < count($datepickers_ids); $i++) { ?>
      $("<?php print $datepickers_id[$i]; ?>").datepicker();
   <?php } ?>
</script>
```

This is going to generate a datepicker for each selector in $datepickers_ids